# Make Google Viritual Tour embeds automatically rotate?

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"       src="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;sll=37.936424,-107.814144&amp;layer=c&amp;cid=12115290478932730695&amp;panoid=YY_tNFWmbOaOJDV_zlAZ0A&amp;cbp=13,40.7,,0,5.57&amp;gl=US&amp;t=m&amp;cbll=37.936374,-107.814213&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=37.935914,-107.813505&amp;spn=0.004595,0.010568&amp;source=embed&amp;output=svembed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&amp;sll=37.936424,-107.814144&amp;layer=c&amp;cid=12115290478932730695&amp;panoid=YY_tNFWmbOaOJDV _zlAZ0A&amp;cbp=13,40.7,,0,5.57&amp;gl=US&amp;t=m&amp;cbll=37.936374,-107.814213&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=37.935914,-107.813505&amp;spn=0.004595,0.010568&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

So there's the embed code.  I was wondering how one might force the resultant content to automatically rotate?  Could I use JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Acessing the components from `iframe`

No, you will can't access the content from `iframe` from Javascript.

The Javascript safety policies do not allow crossdomain access to the document of an embedded (i)frame.

It is called the [Same Orgin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

> In computing, the same origin policy is an important security concept for a number of browser-side programming languages, such as JavaScript. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site – a combination of scheme, hostname, and port number[1] – to access each other's methods and properties with no specific restrictions, but prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites.[1] Same origin policy also applies to XMLHttpRequest and to robots.txt.[2]

---

### Using Google API

The solution is using [Google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) that can connect your application with their service (Street View, in this case).

I think that you need `panControl`.

> A `panControl` provides a way to rotate the panorama. This control appears by default as a standard integrated compass and pan control. You may alter the control's position by providing PanControlOptions within the panControlOptions field.

(search for "Street View Controls" in the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview))

### Sample

Even it's not the best solution I think that this will help you. This will update the `heading` of panorama.

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View service</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var panorama;

        function initialize() {
            var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                heading: 4,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            };
            panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'),panoramaOptions);

            var i = 0;
            window.setInterval(function () {
                panorama.setPov({
                    heading: i,
                    pitch: 10,
                    zoom: 1
                });
                i += 0.1;
            }, 10);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
    <div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 8px; width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also if you want to stop the rotating, add handlers for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for `#pano`, using `on()` jQuery function.

See the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6GBkh/)

Comment: Here's an example of it working within an app for Facebook, any idea how they pulled it off?

https://www.facebook.com/WinnipegGoogleTrustedPhotographer/app_152025171640614

Comment: You are right. I think that they use Google API. See updated answer.

Comment: John - this is a bit over my head.  How would one utilize the panControl field?  Can I just add it to my embed link?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: John, this does indeed help.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Heya John, this works but I was wondering if you could explain to me how to alter the script so it pauses on hover?

Comment: @slothzen, I've update my answer. Also, I repeat it's not the best method.

Comment: John, you've been fantastic.  This has helped me, and I learned a bunch.  In the end I mined through that facebook link's code and found the .js responsible for the effect...long story short I found this tool: 

http://virali.se/photo/spin/

It's ...perfect. haha.  Thanks for all your work, though, you're a saint.

Comment: @slothzen, Thank you! We are learning together... I love StackOverflow so much. You can follow me on Github, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, i get some strange connections from moscow to my server if i use the viralizer.
So I removed it from my page.